# "Update Statistics" operations are dramatically slower after SQL Server Upgrade from 2016 to 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

We recently performed an in-place upgrade from SQL Server 2016 Enterprise to SQL Server 2019 Enterprise. We are finding that some of our update statistics operations are running much slower especially for our larger tables. The upgrade was in-place, no server specifications have changed. The compatibility level has been set to 150.

All of the update stats command use the table as the argument and sample only 20 percent. T-SQL looks as follows:

`UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.tableA WITH SAMPLE 20 PERCENT`

I use sp_whoisactive to monitor live queries for wait types.
We do have some cxconsumer and cxpacket waits showing during these operations. There's no blocking by other SPIDs, no pageiolatch or other wait types.

Does anyone know if there is something different about the "update statistics" operation in 2019 vs 2016? I checked documentation and couldn't find anything.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes we did. Set compatibility level to 150. Tested all of our code as well which checked out fine against the new optimizer.  But we noticed the "update statistics" commands increased in time. We decided to accept that increase and went to production anyway with the upgrade. So we are tolerating it, but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Any changes to the workload group or resource pool in which stats updates are run? Or changes to DOP (system level, database scoped config, statement level for update stats) or Cost Threshold for Parallelism?